# Tycho surefire JUnit tests fail only on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, junit, xtext, tycho-surefire-plugin

I build my xtext eclipse plugin project with maven and jenkins and the junit tests with tycho surefire. Jenkins runs on a 64 bit ubuntu and tests are failing with:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unresolved proxy http://url/from/mydsl#//element. Make sure the EPackage has been registered.` 
I tried to solve this problem with an overidden register function in the StandaloneSetup class like described at [Switching from an inferred Ecore model to an imported one in your Xtext grammar](http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2014/02/) but this didn't work for me.
I tried to run the tests on ubuntu 32 bit and it surprisingly works without failure.

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: you should never call a standalonesetup from a eclipse. ntl how is your target platform look like? does it include 64 bit linux? the epackage should be registered by a corresponding entry in the plugin.xml of the metamodel project.

Comment: p.s: can you share a sample project?

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! Sorry I can't share a sample project, it is not my project and I don't have experience with xtext, I'm only the jenkins guy. I used the tycho:target-platform-configuration plugin with `<environment>
       <os>linux</os>
       <ws>gtk</ws>
       <arch>x86_64</arch>
      </environment>`

Comment: hmm then i have no idea

Comment: Can you share the error message?